# python: TypeError: expected string or buffer: can't reproduce error with prompt

Tags: string, python-2.7

I am trying to debug this function:

```
def check_domains(url):
 global num_websites,domain_queue,domains,doc_queue,stanford_tagger
 the_domain = re.match(r'^(:?https?:\/\/[^.]*\.)?([^/#?&]+).*$',url)
 if the_domain is not None:
  if the_domain.groups(0)[1] not in domains.keys():
   domains[the_domain.groups(0)[1]] = website(doc_queue,the_domain.groups(0)[1])
   domains[the_domain.groups(0)[1]].add_initial_url(url)
   domain_queue.append(domains[the_domain.groups(0)[1]])
   num_websites = num_websites + 1
  else:
   domains[the_domain.groups(0)[1]].add_url(url)
```

error:

```
  File "web_crawler.py", line 178, in getdoc
    check_domains(check)
  File "web_crawler.py", line 133, in check_domains
    the_domain = re.match(r'^(:?https?:\/\/[^.]*\.)?([^/#?&]+).*$',url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I try and be a good boy and test in interactive mode:

```
>>> def check_domains(url):
...  the_domain = re.match(r'^(:?https?:\/\/[^.]*\.)?([^/#?&]+).*$',url) #right here
...  if the_domain is not None:
...   print the_domain.groups(0)[1]
...  else:
...   print "NOOOO!!!!!"
... 
>>> 
>>> check_domains("http://www.hulu.com/watch/6704")
hulu.com
>>> check_domains("https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html")
python.org
```

so this does what I want it to do and I didn't change that line. But why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `url` can still be `None` and that's what gives this error:

```
>>> re.match(r'^(:?https?:\/\/[^.]*\.)?([^/#?&]+).*$', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

So you should check whether the object that you're passing for `url` is indeed a string. It may even be a number or something else but it's not a string which is what the matching function expects.

Comment: Thank you I didn't narrow it down but its fixed somehow